# put_assoc complains of wrong type

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have Ecto schemas representing a directed graph -- there is a `Node` schema with a self-referential many-to-many relation through an intermediate `NodeEdge` schema. i.e.

```
  schema "nodes" do
    field :name, :string

    many_to_many :edges, MyApp.Node,
      join_through: MyApp.NodeEdge,
      join_keys: [source: :id, target: :id]

    timestamps()
  end

  schema "node_edges" do
    belongs_to :source, MyApp.Node
    belongs_to :target, MyApp.Node
    timestamps()
  end
```

with the following initial migration:

```
create table(:nodes) do
  add :name, :string, null: false
  timestamps()
end

create table(:node_edges) do
  add :source, references(:nodes)
  add :target, references(:nodes)
  timestamps()
end
```

I'm trying to bulk insert edges like so:

```
now = NaiveDateTime.truncate(NaiveDateTime.utc_now(), :second)

new_edges =
  Enum.map(
    result.edges,
    &%NodeEdge{
      source: curr_name,
      target: &1,
      inserted_at: now,
      updated_at: now
    }
  )

node
|> Repo.preload(:edges)
|> Ecto.Changeset.change()
|> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:edges, my_edges)
|> Repo.update!()
```

As far as I can tell, this is pretty close to the documentation for [`put_assoc/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4). However, I'm getting an error:

```
** (ArgumentError) expected changeset data to be a Elixir.MyApp.Node struct, got: %MyApp.NodeEdge{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "node_edges">, id: nil, inserted_at: ~N[2019-06-25 23:18:35], source: "nodeA", source_id: nil, target: "nodeB", target_id: nil, updated_at: ~N[2019-06-25 23:18:35]}
```

Is the error perhaps that I don't know the IDs of the nodes in advance? Or can anyone see another problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ab error is pretty self-explained: you are creating a list of `NodeEdge`, and then tries to apply this list to the association `edges`, which is `Node` type.

Bunch of solutions:

- Build `Node` list, instead of `NodeEdge` list. Put this list with `put_assoc`
- Add relation to the node edges

  ```
  schema "nodes" do
  field :name, :string

  many_to_many :edges, MyApp.Node,
    join_through: MyApp.NodeEdge,
    join_keys: [source: :id, target: :id]

  has_many :node_edges, MyApp.NodeEdge, foreign_key: source

  timestamps()
  end
  ```

  Now, put your `NodeEdge` list here.
- Simply create this list - it's absolutely self-explained. Because `NodeEdge` has relations - use them to build associations:

  ```
  %NodeEdge{
    source: put_assoc(:source, curr_name),
    target: put_assoc(:target, &1),
    inserted_at: now,
    updated_at: now
  }
  ```

  Build this list and then save it.

Comment: Thank you! I skipped the first suggestion, since I don't know anything about the neighbor nodes when adding edges, only that there is an edge. The second suggestion raises an error: `field "source" in "where" is a virtual field in schema MyApp.NodeEdge`. An for the final suggestion, `put_assoc/2` doesn't seem to exist anywhere?

Comment: In second: foreign key can be `source_id`. I don’t know the actual schema because I don’t see your migration code - you should catch an idea and perform it by yourself.

Comment: For third - it’s the same `put_assoc` that is in your solution. You should probably import Ecto.Changeset or something to make it work.

Comment: yes, of course! I think I do get the idea -- and in fact, the foreign key in the table is just called `source`. I added the migration code to the question for clarity. It's just unclear to me why it's complaining that the foreign key is virtual when it's a column that exists in the table.

Comment: The key in the migration should be source_id. In current case Ecto doesn't know, what do you want to access - the column in the DB (source) or the relation (with the same name)

Comment: thank you! you resolved the problem i had. due to some specific requirements of my project i can't use the first option, so i am continuing in a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813439/why-does-ecto-think-that-this-foreign-key-is-a-virtual-field